# does each item in ERC-1155 type is unique?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nft

When I create a type of ERC 1155 with multiple tokens, is there a way to identify a specific token, is each token unique?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question right then that would depend on your usage of it.

**ERC-1155** is basically a combination of **ERC-20** & **ERC-721** thereby supporting the development of fungible, semi-fungible, non-fungible tokens ...

So if your looking for uniqueness, non-fungible tokens would basically be that. (hence the term "*non-fungible*")

Answer (score 0):

I believe he is talking about only ERC20 tokens , if so then the token name and symbol is basically the unique identifier.

Reference -

- https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155